# Delete the last node of a linked list. Each node has a data pointer as well that points to some data

Tags: c, data-structures

Hi All
I saw this question posted on a site asked in a technical interview

Node has a data pointer as well as point to some data.

Can somebody help me understanding what this question mean in detail??

Does this mean that Node has pointer to another node and point to some other data node as well. And that data node does not point to any other node. 
In that case our node will have two pointers.

i am really confused. Please Help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.careercup.com/page?pid=linked-list-interview-questions

Comment: @sharptooth  First question on page of above link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should ideally read: Node has a "Next" pointer and the node-data itself is a pointer. Such kind of data structures are common where data itself can be huge and cannot be kept in-memory or within the same node.

Edit:

Looking at the question link: my assumption, mentioned above, seems to be what it is. All you need to do is pick up the pointer from the data field of the node and delete that *before* deleting the node.

Comment: @Vivek Then it should have been : 'node has data pointer and points to another node of same kind '  . Am i right?

Comment: @Rajni Yes and no. Yes because in a linked list any node essentially points to the node of the same kind. No because in the data segment of the node it really does not matter what you fill in. It can be simple data types: int, string etc or a pointer. In this case, it is a pointer.

Comment: @Amit I did not get your question. What stops having a pointer in the data segment?

Comment: @Rajni, in your case the node should look something like this:

struct node{
void* pointerData;
node* next;
}

PS: Omitted obvious syntax

Answer (score 2):

The node structure of your list is pretty clear. In C, it would look something along the lines of:

```
typedef struct list list;
struct list {
        list *next;
        void *data;
}
```

However, if your task is to delete the last node of a linked list, then the task is ambiguous. In single linked lists, you usually insert new nodes at the front, because this can be accomplished in constant time. So it remains unclear whether the "last node" refers to the node that has been inserted most recently (and is hence the front node) or whether it refers to the first node inserted (and is hence the last node that you would see when you traverse through the list).

In the first case, it's really easy to remove the "last" node of a list `list`, because it's the front node: `list = list->next`. You may want to incorporate the edge case of an empty list: `list = list?list->next:NULL`.

In the second case where you are supposed to delete the node that has been inserted first, it's a bit more tricky. You have to traverse through the list, maintaining a pointer to the current element and in addition a pointer to the element before that. Here's some code that you might find useful:

```
cur = list->next;
prev = list;

while (cur->next != NULL) {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->next;
}

prev->next = NULL;

free(cur->data);
free(cur);
```

This code iterates through the list and stops when cur points to the last node (the only list node whose next-pointer points to NULL). Then, we unlink the last node by setting the next-pointer of the previous element to NULL.

Note that you have two special cases:
- the list is initially empty (nothing to do here)
- the list only contains one element (i.e. the first element *is* the last element, switch to the method described earlier)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will clear things up for you a little: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list

Each node in a linked list has a pointer to the next node and some data. The data is never a pointer to nodes in the same list.

edit:
So given a list, you should write a function that deletes the last node and ensures that the new last node points to NULL.

Comment: You are telling what link list is about. Still i am not able to understand the question

Answer (score 0):

Linked list representation: `[data1, p1]->[data2, p2]->[data3, p3]` (p3 points to nothing)

You would be expected to delete data3, p3, AND set p2 to null so that you don't have a lost pointer!

Comment: this is simply what link list is about. then why explicitly told that each node has a data pointer and point to data as well... is there some problem in question or we are not able to properly understand it

Comment: You're right.  On reading it again I'd agree with Vivek's interpretation of the question.  I would rephrase the question as "Delete the last node in a linked list.  In addition to the normal pointer, each node's data also contains a pointer which points to a location outside of the list."

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am somewhat getting what you saying. But it would  have been  more useful if you could provide some rough code in c too.  
Wii it be like
struct Node{
     struct otherlistNode *data;
     struct Node *pt;
   };

And if so, Then how to delete..